# Android Mobile number and when Unstalling ask password for unstall

Tags: android

I want to know mobile number from android apps.I searched in here.some one give this code.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String phone = tm.getLine1Number();
```

but It is not working in mobile It is working in  Emulator.

Mean time when I installed a project that time asked a password and when uninstalled ask password.

Can anyone have idea about this.can anyone help me .please some sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q 1. I want to know mobile number from
>   android apps

Ans. You can't get the mobile number from your application . It is not possible.

> Q 2. Unstalling ask password for
>   unstall

This is simply impossible for a user-level app. For good reason - just imagine putting a malicious app on the market that cannot be removed!

But i have googled on it and find this link . http://www.mediafire.com/?7f52h3bb5tz66am

This is application is simple reading log to implement this but this will stop uninstall all application not a particular application.It has option to set password .so application will be uninstalled by you only after giving the correct password.

Comment: About ans 1: some phone can get the phone number with this code, but not all.